# Using WebBluetooth to access multiple services and characteristics

Tags: node.js, web-bluetooth

I'm trying to read both the weight scale characteristic as well as the current battery level which is on the battery service.

I have the following which works for the weight scale service and weight measurement characteristic but I'm struggling to see how to add the battery service to this (i'm not very familiar with promises)

```
function connectGATT() {
  if (bluetoothDeviceDetected.gatt.connected && gattCharacteristic) {
    return Promise.resolve()
  }

  return bluetoothDeviceDetected.gatt.connect()
  .then(server => {
    console.log('Getting GATT Service...')
    return server.getPrimaryService(wsService)
    console.log(wsService)
  })
  .then(service => {
    console.log('Getting GATT Characteristic...')
    return service.getCharacteristic(wsCharacteristic)
    console.log(wsCharacteristic)
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    gattCharacteristic = characteristic
    gattCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
        handleNotifications)
    document.querySelector('#start').disabled = false
    document.querySelector('#stop').disabled = true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the battery service you need to call `server.getPrimaryService('battery_service')` and then call `getCharacteristic('battery_level')` on the resulting BluetoothGATTRemoteService object. See the full example [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level.html).

The challenge as you've identified is that as currently written using Promises the `server` variable is no longer available at the end of this Promise chain. There are a couple solutions to this. One is to use async/await like this,

```js
console.log('Connecting to GATT Server...');
const server = await device.gatt.connect();

console.log('Getting Battery Service...');
const service = await server.getPrimaryService('battery_service');

console.log('Getting Battery Level Characteristic...');
const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic('battery_level');
```

[Source](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level-async-await.html)

Or you can bring the `server` variable up into the top-level of your function and assign it in the `then()` callback after calling `connect()` so that you can use it from multiple `then()` callbacks.